# Send mail via SendGrid API?

Tags: json, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email in my Angular app via SendGrids API.

I am posting to this URL: `https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json`
With this raw data, to test;

```
{
    "api_user":"MyUser",
    "api_key":"MyPass"
}
```

But i get an error back, `"Permission denied, wrong credentials"`

If i however, set the same api_user and api_key as part of the URL, like so `https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json?api_user=MyUser&api_key=MyPass`, it works.

But as i can have a fairly large portion of data to post (html email body), sending with URL's is not optimal, and it should be part of the post body.

The docs does not reveal much: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

What am i missing?

Comment: Nothing, you're missing nothing. Unfortunately you need pass the parameters as a part of URL. It's not nice, but you can't do anything with that. Alternatively you can generate and use api key and then pass as Authorization header, but the other parameters still you need to pass as a part of URL - lousy consolation.

Comment: @bemol thanks for the input. Even when i make the 2 parameters part of the URL, it accepts nothing i throw at it in terms of JSON. It keeps failing, until i put the same parametrs in the URL?